# How to determine the limit (JS Office Web Excel)

Tags: office-js

I have a piece of code that was supposed to collect lines by condition that I want to delete later and came across an error that seems to be related to the long address sheetQuote.getRanges(**address**);

if I pass sheetQuote.getRangeByIndexes(0, 1, **1000**, 1); then everything is ok

if I pass sheetQuote.getRangeByIndexes(0, 1, **2000**, 1); then I get an error .. how and where can I find out the limits of the address parameter?

Thanks...

```
async function run() {
  return Excel.run(async ctx => {
    let sheetQuote = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet();
    let rangeBoolean = sheetQuote.getRangeByIndexes(0, 1, 1000, 1);
    rangeBoolean.load("values");
    await ctx.sync();

    let rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rangeBoolean.values.length; i++) {
      if (rangeBoolean.values[i][0] === true) rows.push(i + 1);
    }

    let addressesGroupedRows = []
    for (let s = 0; s < rows.length; s++) {
      let endRow = rows[s];
      let startRow = rows[s];
      for (let e = s + 1; e < rows.length; e++) {
        if (rows[e] > (endRow + 1)) break;
        s = e;
        endRow++;
      }
      addressesGroupedRows.push(`${startRow}:${endRow}`);
    };

    if (addressesGroupedRows.length > 0) {
      let address = addressesGroupedRows.join(",");
      let rangeAreas = sheetQuote.getRanges(address);
      rangeAreas.areas.load();
      await ctx.sync();

      for (const range of rangeAreas.areas.items) {
        range.delete(Excel.DeleteShiftDirection.up);
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I tried to find something in the Excel JavaScript API documentation, but didn't find anything specific...

Comment: Can you show some example data? Is there a reason you don't use the entire `usedRange`?

Comment: For reference, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.worksheet?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-worksheet-getranges-member(1)

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, Hello
I have used getRangeByIndexes here instead of usedRange to illustrate the problem.
No one forbids the user to fill out a sheet up to 1048576 lines. And there is a high probability of running into a limit.

Comment: The `address string` is optional and according to docs, if not given, it gives entire worksheet of `RangeAreas`. Perhaps avoid using `address` and you can then loop over the `RangeAreas` and compare w/ your list to do further manipulations?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, I populated 200 lines and ran this ->
let testRange = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getActiveWorksheet().getRange();
testRange.load("address");
await ctx.sync();
console.log(testRange.address);

console -> and got it - > Sheet1!1:1048576

Comment: That is not what I expected. This is a great question. I agree, it is likely a limit of "string length" perhaps, I would have expected a way to just `getRangeAreas` for the `UsedRange` but it appears you need to give it a list of ranges or it just returns entire WS. For example, with `MergedAreas` you can do this `ws.getUsedRange(true).getMergedAreasOrNullObject();`

Comment: `rangeBoolean.values[i][0] === true` doesn't seem to work for me, can you confirm?

Comment: Your code just doesn't work for me, I tried adding data and either `addressesGroupedRows` is empty because `=== TRUE` is never met, if you change to `!= null` then `addressesGroupedRows == row 1 to last used row` no "groups".

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers, In my case rangeBoolean only contains FALSE or TRUE values.

Comment: Can you create a full MCVE for this project, including a "data generator" function so I can reproduce on my end? See --> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

@Sergey, According to my understanding, this API does not specify the limitation of index parameter, but I suspect that you may encounter the problem of payload size limitation because the selected range is too large. Please refer to this link: "https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/resource-limits-and-performance-optimization#excel-add-ins". One possible suggestion is to split the operation, which might speed up the execution and get around this limitation.